# Convert a local time to a specific country time with JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime, android-jodatime

I am having problem trying to figure out how to convert a person's local time to a UK time with Joda.
Say,
31-01-2015 12:00:01am Washington DC time(could be any country's time) to

31-01-2015 5:00:01am london time(London time should always be the output)

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"); DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);
```

Can't seem to format that into this format
**Day-Month-Year hour:min:sec:a**

Comment: hope this will be helpful: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/18812/130743

Answer (score 3):

The input format is in Washington DC time and output is in London time
You can have multiple zone id as input and output.
Get timezone ids from [here](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html) or [here](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/)

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final DateTimeZone fromTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("EST");
    final DateTime dateTime = new DateTime("2019-01-03T01:25:00", fromTimeZone);

    final org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter
            = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
    System.out.println("London time:" + outputFormatter.print(dateTime));

}
```

output:

> London time:2019-01-03 06:25:00 AM

[Ref](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/18812/130743)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to convert from any time zone to London time. Not just from Washington DC time. Like uhm, get the current time using DateTime() or Date() then to London time. Pls add more comments on where I can change from the code. Thanks.

Comment: You can put zone id in the place of "EST" in `fromTimeZone` variable, that's it.

Comment: in order to get country timezone goto https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html